# Trouble with displaying JSON array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, zend-framework

could you please help me figure out why I'm getting "undefined" instead of the value.

As it is plain to see I'm having trouble getting the data from the array, in firebug I get this as a response....

```
{"status":"success",
 "response":[
    {"email":
        {"email":"xxxxx@iing.mxl.uabc.mx",
         "valid":"1",
         "reason":null,
         "confirmed_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
         "contact_email":"1",
         "login_email":"1",
         "users_id":"6375"},
     "history":[
        {"contactRole":"Non Classified Lead with History",
         "contactProject":"2082",
         "contactBrand":"B"},
        {"contactRole":"co Author",
         "contactProject":"32",
         "contactBrand":"B"},
        {"contactRole":"co Author",
         "contactProject":"176",
         "contactBrand":"B"},
        {"contactRole":"co Author",
         "contactProject":"582",
         "contactBrand":"B"},
        {"contactRole":"co Author",
         "contactProject":"1858",
         "contactBrand":"B"},
        {"contactRole":"Author",
         "contactProject":"12",
         "contactBrand":"J"},
        {"contactRole":"Editor",
         "contactProject":"176",
         "contactBrand":"B"}]},
    {"email":
        {"email":"xxxxx@hotmail.com",
         "valid":"1",
         "reason":null,
         "confirmed_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
         "contact_email":"0",
         "login_email":"0",
         "users_id":"6375"},
     "history":[]}]}
```

this is the code referring to my javascript file
http://pastebin.com/gPaEAKim

snapshot of the view that I'm getting.

[image]

Just to be on the safe side...this is the way the array looks like when I debug it from the controller

```
    Array
(
    [status] => success
    [response] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [email] => Array
                        (
                            [email] => xxxxx@iing.mxl.uabc.mx
                            [valid] => 1
                            [reason] => 
                            [confirmed_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [contact_email] => 1
                            [login_email] => 1
                            [users_id] => 6375
                        )

                    [history] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [contactRole] => Non Classified Lead with History
                                    [contactProject] => 2082
                                    [contactBrand] => B
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [contactRole] => co Author
                                    [contactProject] => 32
                                    [contactBrand] => B
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [contactRole] => co Author
                                    [contactProject] => 176
                                    [contactBrand] => B
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [contactRole] => co Author
                                    [contactProject] => 582
                                    [contactBrand] => B
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [contactRole] => co Author
                                    [contactProject] => 1858
                                    [contactBrand] => B
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [contactRole] => Author
                                    [contactProject] => 12
                                    [contactBrand] => J
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [contactRole] => Editor
                                    [contactProject] => 176
                                    [contactBrand] => B
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [email] => Array
                        (
                            [email] => xxxxxxx@hotmail.com
                            [valid] => 1
                            [reason] => 
                            [confirmed_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [contact_email] => 0
                            [login_email] => 0
                            [users_id] => 6375
                        )

                    [history] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: which variable is undefined in the code?

Comment: My guess is it's that it has something to do with using `email` in both of your `each()` loops. Try giving them different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `data` var in your JS code is the entirety of the JSON response, then you're working one level too high, and the inner loop is working 2 levels too high:

```
$.each(data['response'], function(i, email) { 
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^--- missing this

      $.each(email, function(ii, ...)) {
```

as your code stands now, the inner loop's `email` is overwriten your outer loop's as well.

Comment: Don't wanna push my luck...but could I ask you to elaborate this a bit more. I don't quite understand it.

Comment: Your php-side script is sending back a json object, which is presumably the firebug dump you posted. That means the top level of the `data` object is `data.response` and `data.status`. Your first JS .each loop is working on `data` itself, so you'll get the 'response' and 'status' values. Your second .each loop then again works on `data` as a whole, and will get the same two keys.